# Getting the ID of all button using its CLASS

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have the following buttons with same class on my web page.
I searched on stack overflow but I found that all available Links (resources) are related onClick() of a button but I want the list ID's of all buttons **without clicking** any button.

```
<button id="some_id1" class="myClass" ></button>
<button id="some_id2" class="myClass" ></button>
<button id="some_id3" class="myClass" ></button>
<button id="some_id4" class="myClass" ></button>
<button id="some_id5" class="myClass" ></button>
```

I want to get a list of all the button ID's on my webpage **using java script.**
I hope my question is clear :)

Comment: No, it's not; since the 'dupe' requires interaction in the form of a click event.

Comment: And also this question has nothing to do with jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest, given the information available:

```
var idsArray = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.myClass'), function (el) {
    return el.id;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5u24v7vh/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can put this script at the end of your page:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");
var ids = [];

for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++) {
    ids.push(elems[i].id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should log all the ids with the class name

```
var myClassElements = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");

for(var i = 0; i < myClassElements.length; i++){
    console.log(myClassElements[i].id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
for(i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
   console.log(buttons[i].getAttribute("id"));
}
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/904bLvmk/)